# Sparql queries Sparql queries

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need to query dbpedia using sparql:

1. input: name of a person 
   output: 
   the surname, sex , age, occupation
2. input: an organization name 
   output: 
   the founder, if it is public or private
3. input: a date 
   output:
   if it is an important date for Example: christians, or Easter
4. input: a city name 
   output:
   the state, region of the city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for #4

First you need to look at the Ontology Class of City in DbPedia.
city is described as [city](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/city)

```
Select distinct ?city ?location 
Where 
{
   ?city a dbo:City.
   ?city dbo:location ?location.
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Then you can the filter clause to get the city you want.

Answer (score 0):

i think i need to know the resource first but for example 
for the 1. i can do ...

```
SELECT *
where
{
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name_x> dc:description ?p.
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name_x> foaf:surname ?y
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name_x> foaf:name ?y
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name_x> foaf:office ?y
}
```

im checking the others

Comment: What do you mean by checking others? Please make sure that you are here to ask relative question only.